# getting preflight issue in file:/// cordova app

Tags: ios, cordova, backbone.js

I am using this meta tag for CSP-

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap: file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ws: wss:;">
```

And when trying to get local html then its not loading. 
In console also its showing error.

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: Preflight response is not successful (login.html, line 0)
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/.../data/Containers/Bundle/Application/.../test.app/www/templates/login.html. Preflight response is not successful
    success (backbone.js:487)
    l (jquery-2.0.2.min.js:5:24887)
    fireWith (jquery-2.0.2.min.js:5:25704)
    k (jquery-2.0.2.min.js:7:4931)
    (anonymous function) (jquery-2.0.2.min.js:7:8725)
```

Using this code to get local html(Using backbone)-

```
$.get( './templates/login.html', function(data) {
  template = _.template(data);
  _this.$el.append(template);
});
```

Before update above code was working fine. I update iOS and Cordova to latest then I am getting this issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using the WKWebView plugin?

Comment: yes - cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine 1.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be caused by a limitation in the WKWebView plugin where XHR requests to file:// URLs are not allowed. [CB-10143](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10143)

One way to get around this is to use the [local-webserver plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/local-webserver) and use http urls instead.

Comment: Ok thanks @cornor for quick response, I am going to implement the suggestion and will accept answer once done.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [fork](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine) of the plugin which is developed by the ionic team. I know you're not using ionic but it *should* still work with a pure cordova app too as there is no ionic specific code in the plugin. Their version of the plugin fixes some of the existing issues with XHR-requests by using a local webserver.